# Jersey : setting multiple object in response

Tags: java, jersey, satellizer

I am using dropwizard with jersey/jackson and satellizer .

In the signup route by default the returned Object is a JWT token like this:

```
Response.status(Status.CREATED).entity(token).build()
```

So i want to emmbed extra data in the response like the user id and other data.

How could i achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [Jose4J](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/Home) for encoding the returned access_token as the JWT sent back to Satellizer. In the Angular App use [jsjws](https://github.com/kjur/jsjws) or [jwt-decode](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode) to decode your token. Then in your Angular application you handle it in the promise of the `authenticate`:

```
    $auth.authenticate('google',params).then(function(response) {
      $log.log('Authenticated!!!!!!!');
      var token = $auth.getToken();
      var userInfo= jwt_decode(token);
    });
```